# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined at registerNgModuleType

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, devextreme, devextreme-angular

I have a problem that when I clone my repository of the app in angular, after installing the node_module and executing the ng serve it throws me this error and I have already looked for a thousand and one answers but none are correct, the app is from angular 8.1 and my angular global is 11 I do not know if it can influence, but it is with the only angular project that happens to me, at times the ng serve lifts the project and it can be seen but I barely make a modification and I give it save this error appears, I need help that advice me give?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOqph.png)

Comment: Watch error carefully and upload the code file in which it's throwing error. It will give more clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.

I solved the problem by disabled the Angular Language Service for that workspace.
I hope this solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

I could find the error, it turns out that VS code as editor every time I ran the npm install and then the ng serve ran perfect, one time I make a modification and give it ctrl + s it bugea my project and when I run the ng serve me again I get the error, so I had to clone my repository again and work with sublime text and it did not give me the error. It must have been some vscode plugin that makes this happen but it is with very few projects.